# Which word for "foreigner"?

Tags: word-choice

Kio estas la diferenco inter la vortoj "alilandulo", "alilandano", "eksterlandano"?
Se diferenco ekzistas, aŭ oni povas uzi kiel oni volas? Ankaŭ oni ne devas uzi la vorton "fremdulo" por loĝanto de alia lando, ĉu ne?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mi konsideras *-ulo* kiel iom pli familiara ol *-ano*. Jen la tuto.

*Fremda* ligiĝas al *nekonata, nekomprenata* kaj eĉ *maltrankviliga*, ktp. Pro tio mi rezervas la vortojn *fremdulo* por *homo kiun oni ne konas kaj ne plene fidas*, kaj *fremdlando* por *lando kiun oni ne konas kaj daŭre ne komprenas*.

Evidente, tiaj ne estas tipaj sentoj de esperantistoj!

Comment: "-ulo" kaj "-ano" ĝenerale havas malsamajn signifojn. Ne estas tiel, ke "-ulo" simple estas pli familiara sinonimo de "-ano". "-ano" ja signifas personon apartentantan al io, dum "-ulo" havas nur la signifon de persono, sen la signifero de aparteno al io. Kiam oni povas uzi "-ano", oni ĝenerale preferas "-ano" al "-ulo". Pro tio oni kutime diras "alilandano" kaj ne "alilandulo" (kvankam la ĉi-lasta ankaŭ ne estas erara). Pri la signifo de "fremda" kaj "fremdulo", la klarigoj de Antonia Montaro laŭ mi estas pli bonaj.

Answer (score 4):

I think  "alilandulo", "alilandano", "eksterlandano" have more or less the same meaning. The difference is as small, if not even smaller than the one between "alilande"(in another country) and "eksterlande" (abroad).

"Fremdulo", on the other hand, is a bit more vague. PIV presents these definitions of "fremda":

> 1. Senrilata kun la koncernata persono aŭ afero pro aparteneco al alia lando
> 2. Senrilata kun la koncernata persono aŭ afero pro aparteneco al alia persono
> 3. Senrilata kun la koncernata persono aŭ afero pro nekonateco aŭ nespertiteco

When keeping 1 in mind, "fremdulo" would certainly mean "foreigner". However, if we look at 3 the English equivalent is "stranger". To avoid ambiguity, one might instead use "fremdlandano", or one of the other three you brought up.

Answer (score 3):

Kial oni ne povas uzi 'fremdulo'?

Laŭ mi, alilandulo kaj alilandano havas la sama signifo, 'ano' aŭ 'ulo' el alia lando. Sed eksterlandano signifas 'ano' ekstere la lando(ĝi povas esti de alia lando aŭ ne).